# Форматирование в строке вывода времени

Tags: java

Почему-то не получается вывести дату в строке c форматирующим символом `%t`.

Пытаюсь вот так:

```
Date current1 = calGrig.getTime(); // получаем текущую дату
System.out.printf ("текущая дата format 1: %t",  format1.format(current1));
```

А получается только так:

```
System.out.println("текущая дата format 1: " + format1.format(current1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Если внимательно почитать [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) по форматированному выводу в Java, то можно найти следующие строки:

> The format specifiers for types which are used to represents dates and
>   times have the following syntax:
>
> ```
>    %[argument_index$][flags][width]conversion
> ```
>
> The optional argument_index, flags and width are defined as above.
>
> The required conversion is a two character sequence. The first
>   character is 't' or 'T'. The second character indicates the format to
>   be used. These characters are similar to but not completely identical
>   to those defined by GNU date and POSIX strftime(3c).

Формат даты указывается двумя символами: собственно `%t`, указывающий, что параметр нужно интерпретировать как дату, и флаги, указывающие в каком формате дату следует отображать. Например, следующий код выведет дату в соответствии с текущей локалью:

```
System.out.printf("%tD", new Date());
```

В документации приведён полный список флагов форматирования дат.

Если перед вами не стоит жёсткое условие использовать в коде `System.out.printf`, то стоит обратить внимание на класс [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), позволяющий более гибко и читаемо настраивать отображение дат.

Answer (score 1):

Простите, за нескромный вопрос, но почему вы не хотите воспользоваться стандартным форматированием класса String?

```
System.out.println(String.format("текущая дата format 1: %t",format1.format(current1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй класс SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

В разделе Exmaples увидишь форматы на любой вкус

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
System.out.printf ("текущая дата format 1: %s", format1.format(current1));
```

Дело в том, что format1.format(current1), т.к. подозреваю, что format1 это что-то типа SimpleDateFormat, возвращяет String.